# How to Integrate maps to my java application

Tags: java, google-maps, software-design

In my project at college for software engineering, 
I have to make a java application that includes viewing maps of certain cities and editing some content, How can I integrate maps for some cities to my application? there has to be one or more maps for each city. 
Any ideas on how to start?

Comment: I'd start with reading their API docs and tutorials. Besides that, welcome to SO. Please take a [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Is this a desktop application ? Or is this a server application with html + JS UI ?

Comment: @ShamitVerma  It's a desktop application

Answer (score 0):

Two possible approaches :

1. Use map files from OpenstreetMap and display it with : https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JXMapViewer . You can overlay your own data on top of the map
2. Embed a browser component and render map with Google maps / OpenStreetMaps . Howto embed browser component :  https://dzone.com/articles/htmlcssjavascript-gui-java-0 . Map example : https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Using_OpenStreetMap#Web_applications